# Execution stops on Cookies.getCookie() call with no exceptions

Tags: gwt, cookies

I'm trying to read a Cookie value in my server side implementation class. After some debugging my code now looks like this:

```
logger.info("Initiating login");

String oracleDad;

try {
    logger.info("inside try");
    oracleDad = Cookies.getCookie("dad");
    logger.info("Read dad from cookie: " + oracleDad);
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Failed to read dad from cookie", e);
    oracleDad = "gtmd";
}
```

When I execute this code my onFailure block is fired with a Status code Exception:

> com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 500 The call
>   failed on the server; see server log for details

My logging output on the server looks like this:

```
[INFO] c.g.e.server.rpc.MyProjectImpl - Initiating login
[INFO] c.g.e.server.rpc.MyProjectImpl - inside try
```

How is it possible that neither logger, the INFO or the ERROR, fire after the Cookies.getCookie() call? I'd hoped that by adding the catch(Exception e) I'd get some error message explaining why the code fails. But execution just seems to stop silently.

I'm using com.google.gwt.user.client.Cookies. I thought client code can be run on the server, just not vice versa. Is that correct? Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using com.google.gwt.user.client.Cookies. I thought client code can be run on the server, just not vice versa. Is that correct? Is there something else I'm missing?

No, that's not correct, yes there is something you are missing: Server code can't run on the client, *and* client code can't run on the server.

You are not getting an `Exception`. You are getting an `Error` or some other `Throwable`.

Try catching `Throwable` in your try/catch block, and you'll see that you are getting an error where the server JVM is unable to load the `Cookies` class, because something is wrong. The JVM thinks that a native library is missing (because it doesn't know what JSNI is or how to run it), so it throws an [`UnsatisfiedLinkError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html):

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native.

In GWT, the `Cookies` class is meant to interact with the browser itself to see what cookies have been defined on the currently loaded page. To use cookies on a J2EE server, ask the `HttpServletRequest` object for the cookies it knows about, and their values.